# Preserve .md formatting in a new CSS paragraph selector

Tags: css, markdown, hugo

In the .css for a Hugo website, I've created a new selector to perform MLA-formatted indentation of references:

```
.mla-ref {
    padding-left: 36px;
    text-indent: -36px;
}
```

This works as expected, creating a hanging indent. However, the markdown formatting is not applied. I get, for example, a title with literal asterisks: *Moby Dick*

Is there something I can do in the .css item above to preserve the markdown formatting for italics?

Comment: Are you using a theme? Could you also post a snippet of the output markup (the final `HTML`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was to create a shortcode like this that references the paragraph class in the css:

```
{{- $p := .Page -}}
{{- range (split .Inner "\n") -}}
  {{- if gt (len .) 0 }}
  <p class="p2">
    {{ . | $p.RenderString }}
  </p>
  {{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

Full answer [here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/hanging-indent-in-md-maintaining-formatting/25932/2).

Answer (score 0):

### Markdown to `HTML`

AFAIK, you can't wrap the input markdown into semantic sections, as you would with straight `HTML`, for instance. What you get out of

```
# First
This is the first paragraph of the first section.

This is the second paragraph of the first section.

# Second
This is the first paragraph of the second section.
```

is just a pile of

```html
<h1 id="first">First</h1>
<p>This is the first paragraph of the first section.</p>
<p>This is the second paragraph of the first section.</p>
<h1 id="second">Second</h1>
<p>This is the first paragraph of the second section.</p>
```

with those `id`s generated by the content of the heading.

This makes it easy, I guess, to write content and parsers, but hard to apply custom styling only for some elements.

### Markdown in Hugo

Hugo 0.60+ uses [goldmark](https://github.com/yuin/goldmark/) as the default library for parsing `Markdown`, as per the [Configure Markup docs](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/#configure-markup).

Apparently, goldmark supports [custom attributes](https://github.com/yuin/goldmark/#attributes), but only for headings.

```
## heading {#id .className attrName=attrValue class="class1 class2"}
```

This means that at least for now, you could only mark a heading with an `.has-mla-ref` class, and then apply the styling to the immediate sibling.

#### Example

```css
.has-mla-ref + p {
    padding-left: 36px;
    text-indent: -36px;
}
```

```
### Reference {.has-mla-ref}

Best, David, and Sharon Marcus. “Surface Reading: An Introduction.” Representations, vol. 108, no. 1, Fall 2009, pp. 1-21. JSTOR, doi:10.1525/rep.2009.108.1.1

Onwards with your content, this is not a ref anymore.
```

I don't know if there's more to it than just the indentation to make it comply to the MLA format, or if you need more than a paragraph, but hopefully this puts you on the right track.